# Shibboleth installation needs Apache to protect java based application in windows?

Tags: apache, tomcat, shibboleth

I have Tomcat only installed in my app server and I will be protecting with Shibboleth a java based application that tomcat serves. Do I need apache installed as well in order to do that or can I just configure the Apache files that are included in Shibboleth folder.
In other words, the configuration that I need to do to the Apache file httpd.conf, can that be done in the apache module files that shib has since there is no apache files.

Answer (score 0):

You must have some sort of software that can initiate SAML authentication requests and process SAML responses. You can do that in Tomcat using a library and coding much of it yourself, or you can put Apache as a proxy in front of Tomcat, and run the Shibboleth service provider software, which can do both of these things. Also, some containers like Weblogic can handle SAML before it reaches your app.

If you aren't running Apache, you can't expect `httpd.conf` or `.htaccess` files or any Apache modules to work.